# How to convert list of strings into two column data frame base on the subsequent string in the list

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have been able to scrape data from a website but the data are not consistent due to some missing values from ecommerce item, I use beautifulsoup to get the data,
below is the sample dataset in which the ratings are immediately after the product name, some does not have which are followed by another product name, so in that regard i want to set them to 'No rating'.
This is my first time as a newbie to python
Thanks in advance

```
data = ['Samsung Galaxy A12 ',
 '5 out of 5(6)',
 'Screenguard',
 'Samsung Galaxy Mos / A02s ',
 '4 out of 5(1)'
  'Pillow']
```

I actually want to convert it to a data frame base on the subsequent ratings(5 out of 5(6)) under some item, some items has ratings while some do not which is why their is inconsistency in the data.

Expected data frame below

```
   product                          ratings
   Samsung Galaxy A12               5 out of 5(6)
   Screenguard                      No rating
   Samsung Mos / A02s               4 out of 5(1)
   Pillow                           No rating
```

Comment: Why not do this when you are scraping?

Comment: will "out of" be there for rating always?

Comment: no, that is the issue, the "out of" is not always there for product that has not been rated, it won't even have anything, is always blank on the website

Comment: @norie the data are from different class, so my plan was to get them separately, append them to a list and combine all the result into a single dataframe, but when i do that the result doesn't rhyme due to the missing rating for other products, that is why i had to use another method to get the result which i sent here as example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with the posted data but I would recommend you adjust the code you are using to scrape to return 'No rating' when a rating can't be found.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    "Samsung Galaxy A12 ",
    "5 out of 5(6)",
    "Screenguard",
    "Samsung Galaxy Mos / A02s ",
    "4 out of 5(1)",
    "Pillow",
]

products = [product for product in data if not "out of" in (product)]

ratings = []

idx = 1

for product in products:
    idx = data.index(product)

    if idx>=len(data)-1:
        ratings.append('No rating')
    elif  not 'out of' in data[idx+1]:
        ratings.append('No rating')
    else:
        ratings.append(data[idx+1])

df = pd.DataFrame({'product':products, 'rating': ratings})
```

```
Sample Output

                      product         rating
0         Samsung Galaxy A12   5 out of 5(6)
1                 Screenguard      No rating
2  Samsung Galaxy Mos / A02s   4 out of 5(1)
3                      Pillow      No rating
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much, you have saved me from stress

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, I think it is better/cleaner to deal with this while **scraping**.

Here is a code that I think will solve your problem.

```py
#Init data
import pandas as pd

data = ['Samsung Galaxy A12 ',
 '5 out of 5(6)',
 'Screenguard',
 'Samsung Galaxy Mos / A02s ',
 '4 out of 5(1)'
  'Pillow']

# Create function
def clean_data_to_df(data):
    phones, ratings = [], []
    for idx, value in enumerate(data):
        # 1st phone
        if idx == 0:
            phones.append(value)
            continue
        # Add rating
        if 'out of' in value:
            ratings.append(value)
            continue

        # If not a rating, it is a phone.
        phones.append(value)

        if 'out of' not in data[idx-1]:
            ratings.append('No Rating')

    if len(phones)>len(ratings):
        ratings.append('No Rating')
    return pd.DataFrame({'phone':phones, 'ratings':ratings})

clean_data_to_df(data)
```

### Output

```
        phone                   ratings
0   Samsung Galaxy A12          5 out of 5(6)
1   Screenguard                 No Rating
2   Samsung Galaxy Mos / A02s   4 out of 5(1)
3   Pillow                      No Rating
```